# Down for maintainance for a Google App Engine. (Easiest redirection)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, configuration

I have a website running on a google app engine. 
Like any website these days it's a mix of static html pages, javascripts,css, pictures as well as servlets to generate data...

For a few days we want to switch off the site. (The reasons are not relevant)

By switching off I mean that anybody who goes to

http://www.mysite.com/whatever-here

should get a message like:

**[Hi there, we are reworking the site. Come and visit us in march 2013.]**

is there an easy config change I can do so to configure that any call to that domain goes to some simple html page.

In that way I can leave all my web pages in the project and just toggle with this configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java you can add a Filter that redirects all your requests to the page you want.  Or even map everything (/*) in your web.xml to the servlet/jsp you want.

From the [official docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#JSPs):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>disabled</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/disabled_page.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>disabled</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Garcia this is probably the right answer. Can you edit your answer with more content so that I can try it out.

Comment: Done. The servlet Filter option is harder (not much) to implement because you have to add a new Java class. I'd try the /* mapping first. Let us know if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You could deploy a "maintenance" version, with a different `web.xml` that always serve a static html page.

By default it will be served under `maintenance.yourappid.appspot.com`

Then using the admin console you can easily switch the default version to serve `maintenance` by default.

- Go to https://appengine.google.com/deployment?&app_id=yourappid
- Click `maintenance`
- Click `Make Default`

Comment: that's a good answer thanks... however I think Guido's solution is the neatest. thanks anyway.

Comment: It depends, having a `maintenance` version once allow you to switch the default version multiple times, without doing any code changes.

Comment: Whereas Guido solution require you to edit `web.xml` and re-deploy your application each time you need to switch between the two.

Comment: Yes, I like your answer, too. It is probably easier to maintain. With this alternative, could a user still browse oldversion.yourappid.appspot.com and see the old version of the site?

Comment: Yes, any version is accessible with `versionname.yourappid.appspot.com`, and `yourappid.appspot.com` points to the default version.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to your AppEngine admin panel at http://appengine.google.com.
- Select your app
- go to application settings
- scroll down to 'delete or disable app'
- click the 'disable app' button.

Comment: that might not be good enough. If I disable app what will I see ? probably something with the google app engine logo that would confuse my user...